# metadata with deep-links to open my app on android and ios doesn't work

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, meta-tags, applinks

I tried to open app store on mobile when user doesn't has this application and to open application when user has application.

I added meta tags in header of new page open_chat.html:

```
 <meta property = 'al:ios:url'  content = "realagent://chats"/>
  <meta property = 'al:ios:app_store_id' content = "11111111"/> 
  <meta property = 'al:android:url'  content = "realagent://chats"/>
  <meta property = 'al:android:package' content = "com.application"/>
```

After, I do to this page open_chat on mobile and its not redirect me to the app store.

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is it redirecting you to a webpage?
If you don't have web content and just a single application you should add the following to your header:

```
<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />
```

As [the documentation](http://applinks.org/documentation/) states:

Your app may also define a single fallback URL to be loaded in a web browser if your app is not installed. If your app has no equivalent web content, you may specify al:web:should_fallback as false to indicate that other apps should not attempt to fall back to displaying your content in a web browser.